# JQuery Ajax If else

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, alert

I want to make a try catch, when successful, the first condition appears with the message ok and if when it fails, the second condition appears with a message failed in Laravel

But when executed when it is successful, it appears to the second state.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        url: "{{ route('tt.save')}}",
        success: function (result) {

            if (result == "success"){
                alert('Data Succesfull');
                window.location = "{{ route('ttnew')}}";
            } else {
                alert('Data Failed');
                window.location = "{{ route('list-tt')}}";
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error');
        }

    });
```

Comment: are you certain that the response is exactly "success"?

Comment: ``console.log(result)`` and show the result

Answer (score 0):

If your json response is

"return response()->json(['any_veriable'=>'success']);"

then, it won't work.
you have to provide "result.any_veriable".

check your code......